Flask blueprints: declaration on each module __init__.py vs inside routes files
This is my project structure:

As you can see, I have two modules: transactions and categories. I'll use the categories module as an example (the transactions module contains exactly the same folders). The goal is to split the routes and modules based on the domain.
I have two ways to register the blueprints. One of them is causing some weird problems that I don't understand, and here is my question: What exactly is happening?
Way 1
This is my method to register blueprints, called by my app factory:
def register_blueprints(app):
    # ...

    from categories.presentation.routes import categories_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(categories_blueprint)


    # ...


Please, look exactly how I am importing categories blueprint. I am using "from categories.presentation.routes ...". To do this, I have this inside categories routes file:
# imports....

categories_blueprint = Blueprint('categories_blueprint', __name__, url_prefix='/categories')

@categories_blueprint.route(blablabla....)
# some routes

Way 2
This is the original method I have been using, but it is causing a lot of problems.
def register_blueprints(app):
    ...
    from app.src.categories import categories_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(categories_blueprint)
    ...

Pay attention about, in this way, I am using only "from app.src.categories ..." instead of the other "from categories.presentation.routes ..."
How is it possible?
Because I don't have the blueprint registration inside the categories/routes.py routes file. I have this inside categories init.py:
from flask import Blueprint

categories_blueprint = Blueprint('categories_blueprint', __name__, url_prefix='')

from .presentation import routes


Problems caused by way 2
If I import any content from the 'categories' package into any test, it causes an error.
For example. This test works fine:
def test_create_first_category(client):
    response = client.post('/categories/dashboard', data={
        'name': 'New Category',
        'description': 'This is a new category.'
    }, follow_redirects=True)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b"Category successfully created!" in response.data
    assert b"New Category" in response.data
    assert b"This is a new category" in response.data

But, if I write the same test like this:
from categories.domain.category import Category

def test_create_first_category(client):
    category = Category(name="New Category", description="This is a new category.")
    response = client.post('/categories/dashboard', data={
        'name': category.name,
        'description': category.description,
    }, follow_redirects=True)

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b"Category successfully created!" in response.data
    assert category.name.encode() in response.data
    assert category.description.encode() in response.data

I have checked that the problem is the Category import. If I let only the import, even if I am not using it inside the test, still failing. This is the fail:

If I use way 1, then all works fine.
What is happening and what is the differences between that 2 ways of registration?

You need to write a shorter and concise question. Avoid including your frustration in the question and simply write your question without emphasizing certain sections multiple times. Abstractions and reproducible examples play a huge role in question quality, creating a minimal example increases your chances of getting a decent response. Also, always and always, provide the full traceback instead of providing a screenshot of the last part.

Aside from those, I don't think your problem is import style related. The error message clearly says you're overwriting an existing endpoint function. But we have no information regarding to how that happens in this question.

Yeah, this is the rare problem: I don't have any overwritted endpoint and all works changing the way of import
